# Long Azure Data Factory mapping data flow "file system init duration"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-mapping-data-flow

I have an ADF mapping data flow that uses an ADLS gen2 source with a large number of small, say 10kB, files.  98% of the flows time is spent in "file system init duration" in this source.  I can't seem to find any documentation on what may affect file system init, and how to improve it.  Can anyone point me to some documentation on this?

Thanks!
Ed

Comment: Can you try it with the Allow Schema Drift option turned off in the source and see if it improves the init duration for you?

Comment: I too have a data flow with this issue - even when I use the "sampling" or "filter by last modified" options, it takes HOURS to read a hundred thousand files to find the few required to process.
Inline source, JSON, no schema drift option selectable.

Comment: Yea, the prefix filtering is significantly faster than last modified filtering.  I ended up making this reasonably performant by organizing the files into paths that include the datetime, say /year/month/day/hour/minute/second numeric values.  Once you have filtered down to a small subset of files you can apply last modified filtering or other options.

Comment: We also have this problem, it seems a bit ridiculous to spend all it's time figuring out the file system. Compare to "on premise" when figuring out file systems, which happens in a few seconds, our process takes 35 minutes! Ours is using the Common Data Model on Data Lake, which you would think would be optimized.